# Laravel custom validation to all model

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1, laravel-validation

I am using laravel latest version and i have a common field in all model called `slug`.I would to check whether slug is unique or not. i have slug  field in all tables

so i have extended Valdiator class

```
class CustomValidator extends Validator{

protected function validateIsUniqueSlug($attribute, $value, $parameters)
    {

        $isSlugExist= User::where('slug', $value)->exists();
        if ($isSlugExist) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

}
```

this works but problem here is i need to repeat this for models but i dont want to do this .is there any better approach so i can handle it in one method

i know laravel has sluggable package but for some reason i cant use that package

Comment: Why you dont use this ? 
$validatedData = $request->validate([
        'slug' => 'required|unique:users',
    ]);

Comment: @Developer.to avoid table name i dont want to use this

Comment: Okay if you dont use model name try to create one helper for validation dinamic this model name 
2. https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/validation#validating-arrays
is this for define all model name and try this 
$rules = [
    'companyName.*' => 'required',
    'bannerName.*' => 'required',
    'bannerDescription.*' => 'required',
    'bannerURL.*' => 'required',
    'bannerImg.*' => 'required',
];

Answer (score 0):

If you using create cutom rules try this code

`php artisan make rule` command for create rule go to App\Rules dir 
u can see passes function condition here

and use any model

```
'slug'=>[new SlugDomain], in validator
```

Rules file

```
public function passes($attribute, $value)
{
    $isSlugExist= User::where('slug', $value)->exists();
    if ($isSlugExist) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: i dont want to hardcode model name because if i hardcode then i cant reuse this method